# sqlalchemy foreignkey relation with parent class

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, hierarchy

I have the following database schema:

**Parent table**:

1. id - primary key identifier.
2. type - polymorphic_identity.
3. name - string data column.

**Child table**  - inherits Parent:

1. id - primary key identifier.
2. parent_id - foreignkey to Parent.
3. category - string data column.

Summing up I have two tables. Table Child inherits from Parent and also have a foreignkey to it.

**UPD:** I really need both **inheritance** and **foreignkey**. This example is only a short demo which reproduces the problem.

I used declarative_base to declare the schema:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()

class Parent(Base):
  __tablename__ = "Parent"
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  type = Column(String(250))

  name = Column(String(250))

  __mapper_args__ = {
    'polymorphic_identity':'Parent',
    'polymorphic_on':type
  }

class Child(Parent):
  __tablename__ = 'Child'
  id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Parent.id'), primary_key=True)

  parent_id = Column(ForeignKey("Parent.id"), nullable=True)
  category = Column(String(250))

  __mapper_args__ = {
    'polymorphic_identity':'Child',
  }

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://joe:joe@localhost/alch')

session = sessionmaker()
session.configure(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

But when I run the code I get the following error:

> > sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Can't determine join between 'Parent' and 'Child'; tables have more than one foreign key constraint relationship between them. Please specify the 'onclause' of this join explicitly.

I have tried to set relationship attribute myself for Parent or for Child separately and for both too. Tried to use primaryjoin and foreign_keys parameters of relationship. But the error was the same.

I'm totally confused about this error.
I need help.

Comment: You don't need to inherit from `Parent`, because you are identifying that your fk is with `Parent` and there is nothing else that is related. Change `class Child(Parent):` to `class Child(Base):`

Comment: @ShawnMehan I really need the inheritance. This is a demo database schema is used to reproduce the error. My real schema has over 1000+ classes with complex inheritance.

Comment: Can you make a base class thy both the parent and child inherit from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/-JELgarKKZ0).

SQLAlchemy needs a hint in this situation: a **inherit_condition** field in Child's **__mapper_args__** does the trick.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()

class Parent(Base):
  __tablename__ = "Parent"
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  type = Column(String(250))

  name = Column(String(250))

  __mapper_args__ = {
    'polymorphic_identity':'Parent',
    'polymorphic_on':type
  }

class Child(Parent):
  __tablename__ = 'Child'
  id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Parent.id'), primary_key=True)

  parent_id = Column(ForeignKey("Parent.id"), nullable=True)
  category = Column(String(250))

  parent = relationship(Parent, foreign_keys=[parent_id])

  __mapper_args__ = {
    'polymorphic_identity':'Child',
    'inherit_condition': id == Parent.id, 
  }

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://joe:joe@localhost/alch')

session = sessionmaker()
session.configure(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the Foreign Key for the Child id field?

```
id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Parent.id'), primary_key=True)
parent_id = Column(ForeignKey("Parent.id"), nullable=True)
```

You need something like this:

```
id = Column(Integer, auto_increment=True, primary_key=True)
parent_id = Column(ForeignKey("Parent.id"), nullable=True)
```

Comment: That works. The insertion of new objects works fine. When I create schema sqlalchemy warns me with message "SAWarning: Implicitly combining column Parent.id with column Child.id under attribute 'id'.  Please configure one or more attributes for these same-named columns explicitly".

Comment: Ah, no. This method doesn't work as it confuses sqlalchemy inheritance feature. SQLAlchemy started using "parent_id" (instead of "id") in Child table for linking with parent. But I need inheritance link over Child.id and on-to-many over Child.parent_id